# Selecting optimize way to delete rows in oracle though entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, entity-framework, database-performance

I have a scenario in which I have to delete some hundred thousands rows periodically (based on server decision or some fixed time interval). I am using entityframework 6.0 and problem is normal Remove() method is slow for bulk operation. I am thinking of some possible cases:

**Case 1:** Through entity framework, use RemoveRange.

```
var db = new MyDbContext();
var itemsToDelete = db.TableFoo.Where(x=>!x.new);
db.MyTable.RemoveRange(itemsToDelete);
db.SaveChanges();
```

I checked this and this is faster than using Remove alone in foreach. But its still sending oracle atomic sql instead of batch.

**Case 2:** Through entity framework call some procedure or package which in return will perform the delete operation on tables. Though it seems to me as fastest option, but I still have to figure it out here what's the best sql way to delete, I know truncate, but it will not serve the purpose here. What I know is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE deleteDBFoo(p_toc IN DBFOO.TOC%TYPE)
IS
BEGIN

  DELETE DBFOO where TOC < "SOME DATE";

  COMMIT;

END;
```

**Case 3:** To automate this task in oracle(don't know if this is possible or good idea) in-case criteria is to delete all old rows from some fix date-time interval.

What is the optimized way to handle this scenario? If there is some other better way other than these cases, kindly shed some light on this.

**UPDATE1**: After doing some profiling I found the following results:

For deleting 1 million rows in the database

Trunc Table took 3.46 sec.
Case 2: took 37.398 sec
Case 1: took several minutes.
For my solution I will go with case 2, But I still wait for solution better than case 2 or in some way improve it.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to delete bulk data is to do it on the server side.

In your case since you want to use entity framework you should create a stored procedure with parameters, and [execute](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/execute-stored-procedure-using-dbcontext.aspx) this store procedure from code.

The entity framework is slow if you want to use the case 1; because for each delete it creates a query and executes it.

---

Try something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DeleteUnnecessaryData
(endDate IN DATE)
IS
BEGIN

   DELETE DBFOO where TOC < endDate;

   COMMIT;

END;
```

Comment: "do it on server side" how? you mean by using some triggers? 
2nd point your solution seems like Case 2, are you satisfied with stored procedure i have written or there is some better way to do it.
3rd point Ya I agree with you regarding Case 1 :)

Comment: When you create a stored procedure you send to the server only the command for executing the query; the delete from the stored procedure is executed server on the server.

Comment: You write something like db.Database.SqlQuery("exec DeleteUnnecessaryInfo @startdate ", startdateParam)

Comment: Ahh.. I thought where you should call it directly on oracle through some logical triggers or through entityframework app.

Comment: I will test this Case 2, and update my question with proper time it takes in each cases. Then I think it will make more sense.

Comment: A trigger is something else. A trigger executes an action based on a previous action. Example: You want to log every time someone inserts/ updates a table.

Comment: Ya I know tiggers working, I am thinking to automate this process of deletion as much from oracle side, only last thing what do you think about the delete I wrote in case 2. Can this be improved?